# How do I get out of this repetitive BIOS update issue?

Tags: windows, boot, bios, uefi, updates

I did an update to the BIOS in September 2021, bringing it from F.21 to F.22, and I didn't run into any problems until now. I have an HP Notebook 15-dy1751ms, currently on Windows 11.

On the day of Windows 11's release, while I was trying to figure out how to get the upgrade offer to display in Windows 10, I thought of rebooting the computer as a possible last resort. However, when doing so I ended up repeating the BIOS update operation as it was starting back up.

When I upgraded to Windows 11 via the Installation Assist, upon logging in, I saw a warning notification telling me to restart the computer in order to get 'System Firmware' working. I wouldn't think it'd be necessary to keep updating the BIOS over and over again, so I simply ignored the mandate.

But things were unpleasant today. When my tech-expert brother rebooted the PC to update my graphics driver, we ran into the same BIOS update operation, which I see is now making my computer boot longer than usual. We investigated in Device Manager and the 'System Firmware' icon was showing a warning symbol on the right, and the message 'This device cannot work properly until you restart your computer ...' in its properties. We tried rolling back the firmware version to F.21, but this was proven ineffective.

I even lost the ability to access Windows' startup options. Now he believes my device is in an unsupported state, so I won't receive any BIOS updates or rollback at all. I'm worried that if I keep running into too many update operations, my PC may die from a corrupt firmware image. Help me get out of this loop!

Comment: What computer model or mainboard model? I don't see a loop I see an annoyance, but no indication you have a serious problem. You should wait for your MB manufacturer to release a BIOS that supports Win11 and probably in the future wait for the system to support the new OS before installing it. Can you clarify whether there is an actual problem, or just this annoyance each restart?

Comment: I edited the post, so it should now be clear to you. And to mention this, it is particularly annoying on normal boot; but seldom a problem because it hinders the ability to enter startup options/recovery mode. I'm still able to access the desktop, but going into those modes simply repeats the same BIOS update process. I do not have any installation media, sadly whatsoever.